# Between is working fine in SQL Server but losing starting date while fetching same query through PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, date, json

I am having a weird problem: I fired the same query `select DateSpan, PUE from GF.dbo.PUE Data where DateSpan between '2013-10-01 12:00:00.000' and '2013-10-31 12:00:00.000'` in SQL Server and getting proper result.

```
2013-10-01 12:00:00.000 1.66402976232178
2013-10-02 12:00:00.000 1.58132003529595
```

..
..

However when I fetch the same query through PHP script, it loses 1st day. Don't know the reason.

```
SELECT DateSpan, PUE 
FROM [GF].[dbo].[PUEData] 
where (DateSpan >= '$stdate' AND DateSpan < '$enddate')
```

Probably the problem is with later array formulation -

```
 $rows = array();
 $table = array();
 $table['cols'] = array(
 array('label' => 'Date', 'type' => 'string'),
 array('label' => $metric , 'type' => 'number')
            );

$result=sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);

while($r = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) 
{
      $temp = array();
     $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $r['DateSpan']); 
      $temp[] = array('v' => (float) $r[$metric]); 
      $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
}
$table['rows'] = $rows;

$jsonTable = json_encode($table,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Many thanks!

Comment: echo the query, are the dates the same?

Comment: Yes, dates in the query and sql code are the same.

Comment: For further info, it loses 1st day "2013-10-01 12:00:00.000 1.66402976232178".

Comment: I tried "$stdate = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($stdate) - (24*3600*1));" then it is showing correctly, however first date of month is getting lost. It always starts from 2nd date of month. I am using a date picker to pick the date, but they are coming correctly. However while fetching data from SQL Server DB using php it loses 1st Oct. Even it is not fetching any dates before 1st Oct. Not sure why? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I checked and it comes out that i am unable to fetch 1st row of any table. e.g. Date starts from 1st Oct in table. Then I am able to fetch data for all the rows except 1st oct.

Comment: As first date was not coming, i added a date prior to first date and now able to access first dates. Just a workaround!